# Is there a way to block MTG sorcery spells that view my hand?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Sorry if this is an obvious question but I didn't see it asked before and I'm very new to Magic The Gathering.

Is there a way to block sorcery spells in MTG that threaten to view my hand?  For example Thoughtseize from "Theros".  For some reason I don't seem to have a good defense against that.  Can I counter it with a standard "non-creature" counter spell or is something different required?

Comment: If you cast One With Nothing, your opponent will not be able to discard any of your cards. #TechniallyRightIsTheBestKindOfRight

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can interact with [Thoughtseize](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thoughtseize) just like any other card. In particular:

- Yes, you can counter it. Use [Negate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Negate), [Dissolve](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dissolve), et cetera.

  Note that this doesn't really help that much against the first-turn Thoughtseize unless you've got access to a counterspell that doesn't cost any mana, like [Mental Misstep](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mental%20Misstep) or [Force of Will](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Force%20of%20Will). The closest thing you've got in Born of the Gods Standard is [Swan Song](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Swan%20Song) when you're on the play.

  In my experience, the best answer to a first-turn Thoughtseize is to choose initial hands that won't be crippled by it. And, yeah, that's a rather big imposition. That's what makes the card so powerful.
- You can invalidate its target.

  Thoughtseize says "**Target player** reveals his or her hand." If it can't target you, it can't be cast on you. The gold standard for effects like this is [Leyline of Sanctity](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Leyline%20of%20Sanctity), which is actually faster than Thoughtseize if you get it in your opening hand.

  There are no such cards currently in Born of the Gods Standard. :(
- You can take your best cards out of your hand.

  This happens quite a lot in Legacy:

  > "Thoughtseize you."
  > "In response, [Brainstorm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brainstorm)."

  Then you put the cards you need most *on top of your library*, so they're hidden from Thoughtseize but you can draw them next turn.

  There are no such cards currently in Born of the Gods Standard. :(

Thoughtseize is a powerful card (basically the best of its kind) and it's seldom easy to deal with. For higher-level strategy tips, I recommend starting with [Reid Duke's excellent Thoughtseize guide](https://www.starcitygames.com/article/26855_Thoughtseize-You.html) — this'll help you understand what your opponent's going to be trying to do.

Comment: Thanks but I'm confused... Can you elaborate a bit on why "this doesn't really help that much against the first-turn Thoughtseize"?  Do you mean that if I respond with an instant to Thoughtseize and it's the other player's turn, the effect of his/her card always happens first?

Comment: @MikeB No, I mean the first turn of the game. Like this: We start our match. I play a Swamp and Thoughtseize you. You look at your hand: ooh, a Negate! You look at your board: 0 lands to cast it with. Well, dang. And then the Thoughtseize takes your Elspeth because you can't counter it without mana.

Comment: It's worth noting that Thoughtseize is most powerful (and some might argue only powerful enough to be worth the time and mana) on turn 1.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to Alex P's answer, currently one of the most powerful anti-Thoughtseize cards is [Veil of Summer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Veil%20of%20Summer). If you manage to respond to Thoughtseize with Veil of Summer, not only do you stop them from viewing your hand & discarding a card, you also draw a card, effectively gaining a 2-for-1. As a bonus, Veil of Summer is likely to be highly effective against any deck playing Thoughtseize (it stops Black removal spells of which there are many).

The drawbacks are 1) if opponent goes first and starts with Thoughtseize, you won't have the mana to Veil in response; and 2) you need to leave up mana, and opponent can decline to cast Thoughtseize into your open mana. Still, the benefits of succeeding are so strong (& Veil is also effective against counterspells, meaning it is not that narrow a sideboard card) that Veil of Summer is currently banned in several formats.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can stop it with spells that can counter spells like Counterspell or Negate.